# Update section footer title in UITableView without reloading

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to be able to programmatically update the footer title of a section inside a table view, while I am typing text through a keyboard. The keyboard appears when I click on a cell to make its detailedText view editable, so I would like to update the footer title without reloading from the data source.

In fact, if I did this, the keyboard would disappear so it is not a good form of interaction. I've not been able to find a good solution to this problem... any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have groupped table, you can use:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 17)]; //I'm not sure about the frame...
    yourLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    yourLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    yourLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    yourLabel.textColor = RGB(76, 86, 108);
    yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    yourLabel.opaque = NO;
    return yourLabel;
}
```

Declare `yourLabel` in your `.h` file. Then, you can access it via

```
yourLabel.text = @"whatever you want";
```

Please check if that works :)

Comment: Yes, it will probably work. But I will have to handle a large number of groups, so it would be not so easy for me to handle all those different labels. I really would try to do it in a clean way ...

Comment: By the way, what dimensions should I put into the `yourFrame` CGRect instance?

Comment: You can place labels in `NSArray` and then use `for` loop.

Comment: Oops, I forgot about frame. It will be `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 17)`, I think.

Comment: Uhm, I will give it a try ... but, to make it iPad-compatible what frame should I put in there? Or should I just handle the `autoresizingMask` of the `UILabel`?

Comment: Yep, you can assign `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` mask to the label. It should work.

Comment: Besides the autoresizingMask, you'll probably want to set the width to the table's width, and not to a hardcoded value (320 in this case). Also, if you want to go for the default table footer look, you'll want a bit of horizontal padding (i.e. frame.origin.x): 20px on iPhone and 55px on iPad - and of course, adjust the width appropriately.

Comment: I tried this piece of code and, whatever I set as frame, I only get a "compressed" view, i.e. a view whose height I cannot control. Probably returning a simple UILabel as a view does not suffice ...

Comment: So you can return a UIView and put there your UILabel, I think... Sorry, I'm not used to use custom UITableView footers... :p

Comment: Solved: it's as easy as using the `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` method in the UITableViewDelegate class.

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm late to this thread, but I've found you can simply do this:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView footerViewForSection:section].textLabel.text = @"Whatever";
[[self.tableView footerViewForSection:section].textLabel sizeToFit];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 2):

For first section (ziro)

> [self.tableView footerViewForSection:0].textLabel.text = @"test";

Answer (score 2):

Mark Alldritt's answer was good, but sometimes it doesn't size the label correctly. Fixed example is below (for section == 0):

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
UILabel *footerLabel = [self.tableView footerViewForSection:0].textLabel;

footerLabel.text = [self tableView:self.tableView titleForFooterInSection:0];
CGRect footerLabelFrame = footerLabel.frame;
footerLabelFrame.size.width = self.tableView.bounds.size.width;
footerLabel.frame = footerLabelFrame;
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5 Answer

```swift
tableView.beginUpdates()

tableView.footerView(forSection: 0)?.textLabel?.text = "Text Here"

tableView.endUpdates()
```